# How to make the virtual keyboard go away?

Tags: java, android

I have an EditBox in my AlertDialog popup. I made it to popup the virtual keyboard the moment the AlertDialog pops up (so that I don't need to click on that white field to show the keyboard), this way:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
            Asocijacije.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

            if (imm != null){
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
            }
```

But when I'm done typing I need to click "Done" on the keyboard and then OK in AlertDialog. The problem is, that users go right to the OK button once they're done typing and after clicking OK, the virtual keyboard stays onscreen. They now have to click back button on their device. How to clear the keyboard once the OK button is pressed?

Here's my whole AlertDialog code, if it helps:

```
case R.id.bKonacno:

                        }

                LayoutInflater layoutInflaterK = LayoutInflater.from(context);  
                View promptViewK = layoutInflaterK.inflate(R.layout.popup_answer, null);
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilderK = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                // set prompts.xml to be the layout file of the alertdialog builder
                alertDialogBuilderK.setView(promptViewK);
                final EditText inputK = (EditText)promptViewK.findViewById(R.id.userInput);

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                Asocijacije.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

                if (imm != null){
                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
                }

                alertDialogBuilderK
                                        .setCancelable(false)
                                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                        // get user input and set it to result

                                                        //some code of mine
                                                    }
                                                })
                                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                        dialog.cancel();
                                                    }
                                               });
                                // create an alert dialog

                                AlertDialog alertK = alertDialogBuilderK.create();
                                alertK.show();

                                break;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following when `Ok`/`Cancel` button is pressed.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Read [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)  for more. Hope it helps.

Comment: No, this did not work. I placed this code in my OK button, and the keyboard is still here.

Comment: You said that you click 'Done' on the keyboard then then you click `Ok'/`Cancel`. AFAIKiIt should ideally hide itself on clicking `Done` n virtual keyboard without you mentioning anything.

Comment: Yes, when I click Done, the keyboard is gone. Then I click OK to hide the AlertDialog. I placed your code right above my ELSE statement. Is that good?

Comment: Did you try putting it inside `.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {` ?

Comment: Well this where I placed it...that statement goes all the way down to ELSE statement. But, apparently it's not the same if you place this on the bottom or on the top. I don't know why. But once I placed it on the top, right below "public void onClick" it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your buttons:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```