# Hide keyboard before showing DialogFragment

Tags: android

I have a first activity A where the user sets login and password. Then he clicks on "OK" so the keyboard is open and he arrives on the activity B. In the onCreate of the activity B, I display a DialogFrament but the keyboard still open until I hide the DialogFragment.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeolocalisationDialog geoDlg = new GeolocalisationDialog();
    geoDlg.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "geoDlg");
}
```

My question is how can I hide keyboard before showing DialogFragment ?

ps : My DialogFrament is a basic DialogFragment

```
public class GeolocalisationDialog extends DialogFragment {

private static DialogClickListener callback;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        callback = (DialogClickListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement DialogClickListener");
    }
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage(R.string.authorize_geoloc)
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    callback.onYesClick();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.refuse, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    callback.onNoClick();
                }
            });

    return builder.create();
}

}
```

ps2 : I've ever tried to set android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" in the manifest and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following to hide the soft keyboard forcefully:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
// here you may choose the editText where the last time keyboard was opened.
```

See [How to make the virtual keyboard go away?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095075/how-to-make-the-virtual-keyboard-go-away/17095111#17095111) for more.

Comment: In Activity A or B ? I precise if I don't show a DialogFragment the keyboard is automatically hiden when the new activity is started

Comment: You can do this inside `OK` button onClick, if that seems to create an issue. I am supposing its after user either finishes entering password. So do it in first activity. `yourEditText` can be the EditText of your password field.